# Find the matrix representation of T with respect to the standard basis of $P_3$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

$ T: P_3 \to P_3$

$T(p(x)) = p(3) + 2x . p'(x)$

How do I find the matrix representation of T with respect to the standard basis of $P_3$?

I think that the standard basis of $P_3$ would be $\{1, x, x^2, x^3\}$?

Comment: I think the matrix is just diagonal then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's clear that $T$ is linear. Moreover the matrix representation of $T$ in the standard basis is given by
\begin{align}
[T]_{\operatorname{matrix}} = [T(1), T(x), T(x^2), T(x^3)].
\end{align}
Observe
\begin{align}
T(1) =  1 =
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
0\\
0\\
0
\end{bmatrix},
\ \ T(x) = 3+2x= 
\begin{bmatrix}
3\\
2\\
0\\
0
\end{bmatrix}, 
\ \ T(x^2) = 9+4x^2= 
\begin{bmatrix}
9\\
0\\
4\\
0
\end{bmatrix}
\ \ T(x^3) = 27+6x^3= 
\begin{bmatrix}
27\\
0\\
0\\
6
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
which means
\begin{align}
[T]_{\operatorname{matrix}}=
\begin{bmatrix}
1& 3 & 9 & 27\\
0 & 2 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 4 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 6
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{align}