# How to find a matrix $T$ with respect to standard basis $S$ in $\mathcal P_2$ space.

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, linear-transformations

So I have this really interesting question, not a standard "Matrix representation of $T$".

Given $T: \mathcal P_2 \to \mathcal P_2$, where $\mathcal P_2$ is polynomial space of degree 2

$$T(y) = 2y'' + (-x+3)y'+2y,$$
where y belongs to $\mathcal P_2$.

So now I basically just have to find matrix of $T$ with respect to the standard basis $S = \{1, x, x^2\}$ on $\mathcal P_2$.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Calculate $T(1),\ T(x),\ T(x^2)$.

Comment: This is an absolutely standard "matrix representation of $T$" question.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1950082/find-the-matrix-representation-of-t-with-respect-to-the-standard-basis-of-p-3 and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4167924/show-the-matrix-representation-of-l-with-respect-to-the-standard-basis-of-p-3

Comment: Have you had a look at those links, John?